# strange error because of casting tableviewCell

Tags: ios, swift, custom-cell

i double checked the storyboard and i have set the class of the cell correctly and here is the code that generates the warning

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //self.table.registerClass(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "swiper")
    var cell:SWTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("swiper", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SWTableViewCell
    //cell = SWTableViewCell()
    cell.delegate = self
    if (UIDevice.currentDevice().systemVersion.toInt() >= 7) {
        cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsetsZero
    }
    //circ(cell.layer)

    cell.leftUtilityButtons = self.leftButtons() as [AnyObject]
    cell.rightUtilityButtons = self.rightButtons() as [AnyObject]
    /*
    //cell.setCellHeight = cell.frame.size.height*/
    println(indexPath.section)
    return cell
}
```

and the warning disappear if i comment the dequeue line and uncomment this: cell = SWTableViewCell()
and the warning generates each time to dequeue a cell and the warning is :

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7cc50870 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7cc50bc0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc477c0 SWUtilityButtonView:0x7cc53bb0.width <= UITableViewCellContentView:0x7cc50bc0.width - 90>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7cc477c0 SWUtilityButtonView:0x7cc53bb0.width <= UITableViewCellContentView:0x7cc50bc0.width - 90>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2015-08-26 15:08:06.259 swipeTableView[2978:78305] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7cc50870 h=--& v=--& H:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7cc50bc0(0)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf92b90 SWUtilityButtonView:0x7cc536e0.width <= UITableViewCellContentView:0x7cc50bc0.width - 90>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7bf92b90 SWUtilityButtonView:0x7cc536e0.width <= UITableViewCellContentView:0x7cc50bc0.width - 90>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

Comment: Buddy first you need to learn tableView and then autolayout. Don't just start coding read some docs as well to understand how this works.

Comment: 1- i am not using auto layout 
2- i know tableView well ....

Comment: Great!! You are not using autolayout but the errors you getting are from autolayout. If you know tableViewWell then how could you initialize your tableViewCell like SWTableViewCell()

Comment: this is how it's done using custom tableViewCell if you know what i am talking about ...

Comment: You can always deque your cell once registered with the tableView with its cellIdentifier. Then if you are not using autolayout disable it storyboard.

Comment: Remove ```indexPath```parameter from ```tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("swiper", forIndexPath: indexPath)```only the identifier is needed, and with indexPath you prevent table view from working correctly

Comment: thanks guys it turns out that the library i used for that custom cell needs to turn off the auto layout